# Facing a problem for retrieving nested collection data using Mongodb query

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have a three collections, names are "Category", "Subcategory" and "Services". I have tried an aggregate query but I am not able to populate desired result.

I need output as below.
https://www.screenpresso.com/=4LBTc

I have tried the below query

```
PlumbingList:async(req,res)=>{
    const result=await Categoriesmodel.
    find()
    .aggregate([
        {$lookup:{from:"subCategory",localField:"_id",foreignField:"SubCategoryId",as:"sub_category"}},
        {$lookup:{from:"Services",localField:"_id",foreignField:"Services_id",as:"service_list"}}
    ]);
    res.json({message:"categories list",result})
}
```

Can anyone let me know where I am wrong?

Comment: `Categoriesmodel.aggregate` should work. you don't need find method `Categoriesmodel.find().aggregate`

Comment: I need the output as per attached image using aggregate

Comment: I guess your`localField` value and `foreignFIeld` value should be swapped.

Comment: can you rewrite query as a answer

Comment: Please [don’t post images of code, error messages, or other textual data.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors) Hosting the image off-site makes it even more user-unfriendly.

Comment: Which collection name is correct `Subcategory` or `subCategory`?

Answer (score 1):

```js
const sync = async (req, res) => {
  const result = await Categoriesmodel.aggregate([
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: "subCategory",
        localField: "SubCategoryId",
        foreignField: "_id",
        as: "sub_category",
      },
    },
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: "Services",
        localField: "Services_id",
        foreignField: "_id",
        as: "service_list",
      },
    },
  ]);
  res.json({ message: "categories list", result });
};
```